# how to show accuracy in RNN model in tensorflow js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

hey everyone i build RNN model in tensorflow js
that is consept is to predict if there is a special character in a word,
and i want to show to accuracy of the model around all the train time
on the browser using tfvis but i don't see nothing

i create this code and i get in console.log the loss function
and i want to get the accuracy too

```
const run = async() => {
// Define training data
const trainingData = [
  { word: 'hello', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'dani', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'shlomo', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'tyalla', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'toyota', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'test', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'check', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'proud', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'daddy', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'mommy', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'sister', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'train', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'model', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'checking', hasSpecialChar: 0 },
  { word: 'yallla', hasSpecialChar: 0 },

];

// we take all word that we have in the data set
// and count the maximum length of type of words
const chars = [...new Set(trainingData.flatMap(item => item.word.split('')))];
console.log(chars)
// we get the max length of word from dataset
const maxLen = Math.max(...trainingData.map(item => item.word.length));

const xs = tf.tensor(trainingData.map(item => {
  // We encode each word to numbers from chars that we create in line 32
  const encoded = item.word.split('').map(char => chars.indexOf(char));
  // we create a padding to each word
  // that she will be the same with the max length word
  const padding = Array(maxLen - item.word.length).fill(0);

  // concat the encode with padding to create one tensor with all data
  const conc =  encoded.concat(padding);
  return conc
}), [trainingData.length, maxLen, 1]);

const ys = tf.tensor2d(trainingData.map(item => [item.hasSpecialChar]));

// Define the model architecture
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.lstm({ units: 32, inputShape: [maxLen, 1] }));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid' }));

// Compile the model
model.compile({ loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', optimizer: 'adam', metrics: ['accuracy'] });



// Train the model
const epochs = 400;
await model.fit(xs, ys, { 
  epochs,
  shuffle: true,
  // acccc 
  callbacks: {
   
    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log(`number of epoch: ${epoch}, loss: ${logs.loss}`)
  }
  }
 })
//  .then(() => {
  // Test the model
  const testWords = ['david', 'wolf$', 'test', 'gmail@', 'papa<>br'];


  const testXs = tf.tensor(testWords.map(word => {
    const encoded = word.split('').map(char => chars.indexOf(char));
    const padding = Array(maxLen - word.length).fill(0);
    return encoded.concat(padding);
}), [testWords.length, maxLen, 1]);

  const predictions = model.predict(testXs).dataSync();

  console.log('Predictions:');

  predictions.forEach((prediction, i) => {
    const word = testWords[i];
    const hasSpecialChar = prediction >= 0.5 ? 'yes' : 'no';
    console.log(`${word}: ${hasSpecialChar}`);
  });
// });
}

run()
```

i try to add that to model
but i get nothing on browser

```
 const acccc = tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
  { name: 'Training Performance' },
   ['loss', 'accuracy'],
   { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
 );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.